# matlab - graph plotting

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays to plot, in x axis : array `a`. In y axis array `b` (ones and zeros)

I want to plot vertical lines when the values of array b =1
i.e

```
a=[23 12 76 43 21 90]
b=[1 0 1 1 0 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try [bar plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bar.html).

```
a=[23 12 76 43 21 90];
b=[1 0 1 1 0 1];
bar(a,b)
```

[image: bar plot]